# Bidirectional Mapping One to Many

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I am using

> hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final jar
>
> hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final
>
> hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final

My entity classes Company and Branch:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID") @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Branch> branchs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "branch")
public class Branch {
    @Id @Column(name = "ID") @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
}
```

I am getting error on executing in HQL

> session.createQuery("select new Company(id, name, branchs) from Company as company").list()

I am having constructor in Company  Company(id, name, branchs)

The error is:

> 2013-12-06 16:28:02 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:145 - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
> 2013-12-06 16:28:02 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - You have an error in your SQL        syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_2_0_ from company company0_ inner join branch branchs1_ on company0_.ID=b' at line 1

[image: Apache Tomcat Error]
[image: Apache tomcat error]

Comment: you want select id, name, branchs of all records into company table or you want to select specific company record ?

Comment: May I ask why you're doing this? Why not simply `select c from Company c`?

Comment: @mabi It is bidirectional mapping. So If I am having a column in for company id  branch and If i want to retrive all companies with their branch in Company pojo. So I am doing this. Please suggest me if the same is possible in other ways.

Comment: @Ashish I want select id, name, branchs of all records into company table.

Comment: I have reffered http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: I was referring to your query and the `new Company()` use. Why do you need that (note, I'm curious, for your problem see @Mathias' answer)?

Comment: @mabi Ok thank you, let me go through that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your hibernate.dialect property. Have you configured it for MySql.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Yes I am using<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all records from Company table then you can use following HQL

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Company AS c");
query.list();
```

or if you want to add some condition then your HQL should be like this

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT c.id, c.name, c.branchs FROM Company AS c WHERE c.id = :id AND c.branchs = :branchs");
query.setParameter("id", 123);
query.setParameter("branchs", "abc");
query.list();
```

Comment: It is not working as it is again with a exception ie Bad SQL grammer

Comment: SELECT c.id, c.name, c.branchs FROM Company AS c

Comment: when you use createQuery() the you can pass only HQL query and if you want to execute native query then you should use createSqlQuery() method of hibernate.

Comment: I think you are mixing HQL query and native query togather

Comment: Ashish it is also a HQL query

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following annotiations:

I assume company is the owner of the data:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn (name = "ID")
private Set<Branch> branchs;
```

In the Branch class I would annotate the company instance variable as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name="ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Company company;
```

Like this the join is made on the ID column of your Company class and you have the benefit that no link table is created.

Comment: I cant get this. would you please explain it?

Comment: To map a bidirectional one to many, with the one-to-many side as the owning side, you have to remove the mappedBy element and set the many to one @JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to false. More info can be found in the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html, more specific under 2.2.5.3.1.1. Bidirectional